# How to read the if statement inside a double for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem with my code.These are just example of my program. I have a for loop inside a for loop and a if statement. My goal is that i want to print the output below

```
The dogs that i like are
bulldogs
poodle
beagle
pug

The dogs that i don't like are
boxer
rottweiler
bullterrier
sheltie
```

I tried this code but it seems like there's something wrong.

```
sample = [['The dogs that i like are'], ["The dogs that i don't like are"]]
sample_2 = ['bulldogs', 'poodle', 'beagle','pug', 'boxer', 'rottweiler','bullterrier','sheltie']

i = 'pug'

for s in sample:
    print (sample)
    for s2 in sample_2:
        print (sample_2)
        if sample_2 == i:
            print ("\n");
```

Comment: Step away from the computer and get a piece of paper and pencil. Write **in words** the steps to solve your problem. You need to have a very good idea in your mind of these steps before you can attempt to write a computer program to perform them. From the list of all dogs, how do you decide which dogs should be in the "I like" list and which should be in the "I don't like" list? Maybe you need two lists, `like` and `dont_like`, rather than just one list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've had the *walk away from the computer*

Approach:

1: Make 2 lists, one with the names of all the dogs that you like and the other with the ones you dont.

2: Iterate over the lists to print their names.

```
liked_dogs = ['bulldogs', 'poodle', 'beagle', 'pug']    
not_liked_dogs = ['boxer', 'rottweiler', 'bullterrier', 'sheltie']


print("The dogs that I like are")
for dog in liked_dogs:
    print(dog)

print("\n")
print("The dogs that I don't like are")
for dog in not_liked_dogs:
    print(dog)
```

OUTPUT:

```
The dogs that I like are
bulldogs
poodle
beagle
pug


The dogs that I don't like are
boxer
rottweiler
bullterrier
sheltie
```